# Prevent window from closing

Tags: window

Often I'll open a program from terminal (gedit, or some software I'm working on, etc.) then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to close the program... then press it again closing the terminal even though I'm not done with it.

Is there a way I can 'pin' a window so as to prevent it from closing, but easily be able to unpin it to close the window?

Comment: I don't think you're going to get an immediate answer with a simple solution.  You're probably looking at overriding the alt-f4 shortcut to launch a script/code-blob that checks the caller/active window and makes a determination from there on whether to send a kill signal or not.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and found a solution for KDE Plasma 5.

In KDE you can edit application window/application settings (right click on the title -> More Actions -> Special Application Settings) and make window non-closeable. After that you can only use application menu to exit.

Comment: Thank you - that worked!
It's in the "Appearance & Fixes" tab:
  Check "Closable", 
  Select "Force" and 
  Radio button "No"

Answer (score 0):

This would probably be more appropriate as a comment, but I can't make one yet.

If the primary problem you're having is accidentally closing your terminal, I suggest looking into **[Guake](http://guake.org/)**. It is an amazing terminal emulator that drops down from the top of the screen. Always there when you need it and you won't accidentally close it. I personally mapped the pull-down to ` like the console in many video games.